# Iteration error in Django

Tags: python, html, sql, django, email

I'm still a student so sorry if I make stupid mistakes and the code looks a lil ugly, I still need to clean it up. I'm busy with a project where we have to make an online webshop. The database is already set-up and so is the email-system, but whenever I try to implement the ordered data (items that got added to your ShoppingCart), I'm unable to specify the items in an email. **A heads up**, I have written a lot of info down below to make the error as clear as possible.

**This is the error I got:**

TypeError at /checkout/
'OrderDetails' object is not iterable
Error during template rendering

```
16  {% for createOrder in order %}
```

**This is the email html:**

```
<!--This order email-->
{% load custom_tags %}
{% load shoppingcart_tags %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<style type="text/css">
body.login {background-color: palegreen;}
</style>
{% endblock %}

{% autoescape off %}
<p>Beste klant,</p>
    <p></p>
<p>U heeft zojuist een bestelling geplaatst op onze website voor de volgende producten:</p>

{% block purchases %}
{% for createOrder in order %}
   <h1>{{ orderDetails.orderNum }}</h1>
   <h1>{{ orderDetails.productNum }}</h1>
   <h1>{{ orderDetails.amount }}</h1>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

<p>Wij streven ernaar uw bestelling binnen 2 dagen tijd bij u te leveren.</p>
<p>Als u nog enige vragen heeft, wees dan niet bang ons te contacteren via onze online contact forum</p>
<p>http://HiddenName.com/contact/</p>
    <p></p>
<p>Wij hopen u hierbij genoeg van dienst geweest te zijn.</p>
    <p></p>
<p>Met vriendelijke groeten,</p>
    <p></p>
<p><strong>HiddenName</strong></p>

{% endautoescape %}
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the logic behind the email:**

```
from django.db.models import Max

from ..models import Orders, OrderDetails, ShoppingCart, Customers, Address
from django.utils import timezone
from .CartOps import clearCart
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMultiAlternatives
from ..models import  OrderDetails

def createOrder(request):
    date = timezone.now().date()
    status = "Processed"

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        custID = createCustomer(request)
    else:
    custID = request.user.id

    orderEntry = Orders(orderNum=getNewOrderNum(), orderDate=date, orderStatus=status, customerID=Customers(customerID=custID))
    orderEntry.save()
    for e in ShoppingCart.objects.all().filter(session_key=request.session.session_key):
        orderDetailsEntry = OrderDetails(amount=e.amount, orderNum=Orders(orderNum=orderEntry.orderNum), productNum=e.prodNum)
        orderDetailsEntry.save()

    createAddress(request, custID) #Sla het adres op, of update deze indien nodig

    c = request.session['customer_email']

    order =  orderDetailsEntry
    html_content = render_to_string('mail/order_complete_email.html', { "order" : order })
    text_content = render_to_string('mail/order_complete_email.txt')

    email = EmailMultiAlternatives("Your order details", text_content, 'noreply@HiddenName.com', [c])
    email.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html"))
    email.mixed_subtype = 'related'

    email.send()

    clearCart(request) #Clears Shoppingcart
```

PS: I'm aware the "order =  orderDetailsEntry" isn't necessary, I was just trying to follow a guide which I still had to change up.

**And if needed, this is how the model looks like:**

```
class OrderDetails(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('orderNum', 'productNum')
        verbose_name_plural = "Order details"

    orderNum = models.ForeignKey(Orders, db_column='orderNum')
    productNum = models.ForeignKey(Products, db_column='productNum')
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.orderNum))
```

Comment: What do you expect `{% for createOrder in order %}` to do? Perhaps you should remove that `{% for %}` tag and ``{% endfor %}` tag, and simply do `{{ order.orderNum }}`, `{{ order.productNum }}`, `{{ order.amount }}`.

Comment: I thought if I'd do it this way, that it would iterate over all the available items in the cart and giving their properties, but I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a confusion. You cannot iterate over `order` which is an `orderDetailsEntry` according to your `views.py`.

`orderDetailsEntry` is not iterable as this is a new row you just inserted into DB, and not a queryset.

Maybe you want to do something like the following ?

`order = OrderDetails.objects.filter(amount=..., orderNum=..., productNum=...)`

Comment: I'll try, one sec. That was indeed the issue I was having though yeah.
Do you think I should get rid of my ''for createOrder in order'' loop or is it that alright?

Comment: Technically if you want your loop to work in template you should indeed replace `{% for createOrder in order %}` with `{% for orderDetails in order %}`. Apart from that I cannot tell you if this is what you really want to do. We should have to talk more about the logic of your project ;)

Comment: After updating the server and running it, I got this error:    
DoesNotExist at /checkout/    
OrderDetails matching query does not exist.   
But I'll try to implement your latest change.

Comment: Strange you're getting a `DoesNotExist` exception because it only happens whith `get()`, not with `filter()`. If you actually used `get()` instead of `filter()` then `DoesNotExist` simply means the query to DB returned no result (the row you're looking for does not exist in DB).

Comment: I'm asking the people I'm working with now if the database's data got injected properly, as this is indeed quite odd